# yfonts in XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I like very much fonts included in the package `yfonts`. I'm currently using XeLaTeX. I have such code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\begin{document}
 \textswab{This: is: the Title}
\end{document}
```

This works but I would like to select the three fonts Fraktur, Schwabacher, and Gothic, direcly using the `fontspec` package. Notice that I would like to use *the same fonts provided in the `yfonts` package*. How can I do?

Comment: You build an OpenType version of the fonts. Nobody has yet, as far as I know.

Comment: Why do you even *need* to use the fonts direcly from `fontspec`? Use them as they are.